# Steinhausen set in $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory

Does every Steinhausen set have positive lebesgue measure? Steinhausen set is a set $A\in [0,1]:0\in \operatorname{int}(A-A),\mu(A)\geq 0$.

Comment: Perhaps, [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA87&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)?

Comment: Who is Steinhausen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The Cantor set has measure zero, yet $0$ is an interior point of its difference set (in fact, the difference set is $[-1,1]$). A proof of the latter fact can be found in Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis*. See, [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA87&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).